# Tool or service to generate valid word types based on grammars

Tags: word-choice, grammar

The sentence below has several tokens (`T1` - `T5`):

> To gain T1, you must T2 it from T3 T4 T5.

I'm trying to figure out what the values for each token could be, but can't even figure out what *types* of words each token is (noun, pronoun, adverb, etc.).

Is there a service or website that would generate the word types for me (for instance, if `T1` was the word "*access*", this tool would hopefully show `T1` as having **verb** as a valid word type, etc.

If not, can anyone spot what (from a valid syntax/grammar standpoint) the valid word types for each token are?

Comment: What's your final objective here? What will the word types of the various tokens tell you, or allow you to do?

Comment: If there's just a single word missing, it can generally be possible to determine with reasonable accuracy what part of speech it should be.  But where you have T3 T4 T5 it can be basically impossible, given that I could set it up to be "newly coined words" (adv, adj, n), "new attorneys general" (adj, n, adj), "a big bear" (art, adj, n), "people like me" (noun, prep, pron), etc.

Now, if you have a giant database of POS-n-grams, you could maybe spit out a range of options ranked by likelihood, but that'd be the best you can do.

Comment: And why not just look them up in a dictionary? Or train up a daemon to do it for you.

Comment: To add to guifa's comment, even T1 could be a noun (*access*), an adverb (*quickly*), or a pronoun (*these)*, and that is assuming that *to gain* is the head of an infinitive phrase. But *to* might be a preposition, and/or *gain* might be some jargon or slang and a noun or adjective, say. And what if T1 is *charley horse*?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a faulty premise about English.